# Magento display tier prices instead

Tags: magento

I've looked through Magento forums and here on SO, but haven't come across the proper answer.

I simply need to replace the displayed normal price on product pages (and category pages also) with the lowest tier price.

Had the thought of replacing price.phtml ~ line 59:

```
$_price = $_taxHelper->getPrice($_product, $_product->getPrice())
```

With:

```
$_price = $_tierPrices
```

(while declaring $_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices above).

Any suggestions welcome.

---

Solved:
found solution at:

http://www.e-commercewebdesign.co.uk/blog/magento-tutorials/get-lowest-tier-price.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found another method for this, which basically takes:

```
$_tierPrices = $this->getTierPrices();
```

...and splices the array to get the first tier.

```
$_firstTier = array_slice($_tierPrices, 0, 1);
```

Then you can just cycle through $_firstTier and grab the 'price' value:

```
$c = count($_firstTier);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $_firstTierPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($_firstTier[$i]['price']);
}
echo $_firstTierPrice;
```